# Python Anaconda - gphoto2

Tags: python, anaconda, libgphoto2

OS: LINUX - UBUNTU

I downloaded and installed gphoto2 following the instructions given in this link: 
https://hyfrmn.wordpress.com/2015/02/03/install-libgphoto2-and-gphoto2-from-source-on-raspberry-pi/

It is working as a charm on terminal. I can type in gphoto2 as a command line and capture or download images and do a wide variety of things.

Previously, I have Anaconda2 installed. I run python programs through pycharm and everything works fine. Now when I wanted to import gphoto2 to my python script, it is showing an error no module named gphoto2.

How would I fix this. It might the problem of an environment, but what would be the way to link them. I have anaconda2 installed on my home directory and I have no idea, where gphoto2 was installed.
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: `gphoto` doesn't appear to have a Python interface at all, at least based on that link. You have to find out if `gphoto` can be installed into Python

Comment: It does. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gphoto2/

Comment: Did you install the Python package?

Comment: I have Anaconda installed.

Comment: Yes, but did you specifically install the gphoto2 python package?

Comment: it CAN be installed, verified!

Answer (score 0):

you can still install gphoto2 via pip in your environment,

```
pip install gphoto2
```